Problem 6.2.10 From Complex Analysis by Jihuai Shi
Definition: let $f$ be holomorphic on a region $G$ (here region means a non-empty connected open set). For $\xi\in \partial G$, if there exists a ball $B(\xi,\delta)$ and a holomorphic function $g \in \mathscr O(B(\xi,\delta))$ such that $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in G\cap B(\xi,\delta)$, then $\xi$ is called a regular point for $f$, otherwise it is called a singular point.
The problem is:
Set $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n$ a power series with convergence radius $r=1$, and $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n =0$. If $z_0\in \partial B(0,1)$ is a regular point for $f$ (as defined above) then $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z_0^n$ converges.
My try:

I considered prove it by Cauchy's Criterion, by trying to control $|\sum_{p=1}^{N} a_{n+p} z_0^{n+p}|$, but the triangular inequality leads to $\sum_{p=1}^{N} |a_{n+p}|$ which couldn't be controlled.

I considered Taylor expansion at $\frac{z_0}{2}$ and using 'the convergence radius here is larger then $\frac {1}{2}$', but I don't know how to transform it to useful information.

I realized that the $\lim a_n =0$ condition is necessary, for $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n z^n$ has $z=-1$ as a regular point, but the power series doesn't converge here. This example also reminds me that the property of $f$ on boundary is unknown.

I think that maybe I can make use of something like uniform convergence to make the limit and sums exchangeable here (not all the time, see 3), but I don't understand how.


Thank you for your reading and answer!

In the definition, $\xi$ should be $z_0$, and $D$ should be $G$?

The correct term is "radius": radium is a radioactive substance.  There are enough hits on google for "homolophic" to make me second guess my gut impression it is a typo. Is it not just a misspelling of "holomorphic"?

To Just a user and rschwieb: Yes you're right and I just corrected them. I'm sorry for misspelling and thank you for pointing them out! (I don't know how to at two users at the same time :( )

this is called Fatou Tauberian theorem and is quite a non-trivial result; it is sometimes called Fatou-Riesz or Riesz Tauberian theorem too; in Landau seminal analysis book Darstellung etc-it is #18 Satz von M Riesz and the rigorous explicit proof there is a few pages long, while the argument is sketched in Korevaar Tauberian bible (12 - p 148);  a similar proof (also about 2 pages long) is given in the classic book The Theory of Functions by Titchmarsh (7.31) so would recommend to consult one of these sources or similar

@Conrad, if you post your comment, I'll upvote it.
